# How to automaticly approve opening of new window for authenticating

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm using office js helpers for a word addin, that is a collection of helpers to simplify development of Office Add-ins. in my case it is the authentication that is used.

When you open the addin. The authentication proccess starts and it opens up a small window with the text(translated to english)

```
Templatehandler wants to open a new window

                          Allow or Ignore
```

(Allow or ignore are buttons)

The company that I work for wants this proccess to be automated - It should be allowed right out of the box. How do I acomplish that?

Comment: What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: In this case, it's a platform limitation/issue, so I think that MangeD66's question here is the correct thing.  @MangeD66, I encourage you to also file a bug on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues so that it can be tracked there in addition to having the platform team's visibility to it here.

Comment: (And actually, I see that you did file an issue on https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-helpers/issues/56; but for this one, it's really a platform issue, not a helpers issue, so the "office-js" repo is the more appropriate place.  Thank you very much for channeling your feedback to the team!)

Comment: Thank's Michael! =) I will file a bug at the right place as you mentioned. I really love your book by the way =O)